# Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client and add parameter with addwithvalue / DBNull

Tags: vb.net, oracle, parameter-passing, dbnull, oracle-manageddataaccess

this i my query and parameter list i got msg "Not All Variable bound"

```
Dim cmd As New OracleCommand("select POLICY_REFER, ....

from   POLICY_MASTER
where  ISSUE_DATE BETWEEN :DFrom AND :DTo 
                           And    (CLIENT_NAME = :client or :client is null)  
                           and    (POLICY_PRODUCT = :product or :product is null)
                           and DOC_STATUS = 'Parked'", sgcnn)

cmd.Parameters.Add("@DFrom", OracleDbType.Date).Value = DtpFrom.Value.ToShortDateString
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DTo", OracleDbType.Date).Value = DtpTo.Value.ToShortDateString
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Product", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = CmbProduct.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Client", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = CmbClient.Text
```

if i used just client_name in query in parameter list then it work but when i used client_name and product i got msg "Not All Variable bound"

Comment: Have you tried specifying `System.DBNull.Value` as the value?

Comment: No, how and where i can try this (System.DBNull.Value) ??? please explain little more

Comment: Well - `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Product", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = System.DBNull.Value` for instance

Comment: i tried this like If CmbProduct.Text = "" Then

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Product", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = System.DBNull.Value

            Else

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Product", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = CmbProduct.Text

            End If     -----------    ----------------------------------------------------------------Catch ex As Exception == Not All Variable bound ......

Comment: What if you do `AddWithValue` instead. So `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product", System.DBNull.Value)`

Comment: I'm using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client and its not support AddWithValue ... is not a member of oracle parameter collection .... this is the real issue

Comment: I would prefer `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Product", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(CmbProduct.Text), DBNull.Value, CmbProduct.Text)`

Comment: If you get an `Not All Variable bound` then the error might be somewhere else. Please show us more of your code.

Comment: Dim cmd As New OracleCommand("select POLICY_REFER,
       END_REFER,
       CLIENT_NAME,
       POLICY_PRODUCT,
       ISSUE_DATE,
       GROSS,
       DOC_TYPE,
       DOC_STATUS
from   POLICY_MASTER
where  ISSUE_DATE BETWEEN :DFrom AND :DTo 
                           And    (CLIENT_NAME = :client or :client is null)  
                           and    (POLICY_PRODUCT = :product or :product is null)
                           and DOC_STATUS = 'Parked'", sgcnn)

Comment: cmd.Parameters.Add("@DFrom", OracleDbType.Date).Value = DtpFrom.Value.ToShortDateString
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DTo", OracleDbType.Date).Value = DtpTo.Value.ToShortDateString
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Product", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = CmbProduct.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Client", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = CmbClient.Text

Comment: Please edit you question with additional code instead of putting into a comment.

Comment: i sent you both query and parameter list , query is working fine in sql developer but make problem in vb.net , if i used client_name in query and parameter list then its will work but when i use both client_name and product then i get msg Not All Variable bound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You SQL string has six parameters

```
**:DFrom** AND **:DTo** 
And    (CLIENT_NAME = **:client** or **:client** is null)  
and    (POLICY_PRODUCT = **:product** or **:product**
```

Thus you must provide six parameters:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("DFrom", OracleDbType.Date).Value = DtpFrom.Value
cmd.Parameters.Add("DTo", OracleDbType.Date).Value = DtpTo.Value
cmd.Parameters.Add("Client", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(CmbClient.Text), DBNull.Value, CmbClient.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add("Client", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(CmbClient.Text), DBNull.Value, CmbClient.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add("Product", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(CmbProduct.Text), DBNull.Value, CmbProduct.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add("Product", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(CmbProduct.Text), DBNull.Value, CmbProduct.Text)
```

I don't know whether `@` is permitted/required for parameter name. Then you should remove `ToShortDateString`. Parameter is declared as `OracleDbType.Date`, so just provide the `DateTime` value, you don't have to consider any format topics - that's a major benefit of using bind parameters instead of putting the values as strings.

Comment: Thank you Wernfried Domscheit, its working as its should be, please explain little why client and product parameter add twice and  IIF (if with two II ) ???, basically im business analyst ... not a programmer  doing this programming job after 15 years

Comment: `IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(CmbClient.Text), DBNull.Value, CmbClient.Text)` is just a shortcut for `If String.IsNullOrEmpty(CmbClient.Text) Then DBNull.Value Else CmbClient.Text End If`

Comment: You defined the parameter twice in your SQL statement (even though they have the same name, the position and total number counts), thus you must provide it also twice.

Comment: Once again Thank you  Wernfried Domscheit... im developing an application using oracle 11g, vb.net 2015 and Crystal Reports on window 10, can you give advise/tips   how i can deploy the  application on client/server , i created a package and install an other pc on same network package is running fine but unable to connect to the database...

Comment: Please open a new question for that - with code and proper error messages.